# Passing geolocation fetched from the app to the UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, geolocation

I'm developing the iOS app and in one of the views I would like to include UIWebView with a page that contains a map (the address is: https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de). The website requires location permission so as soon as the user is presented with this view, an alert appears: "https://carsharing.mvg-mobil.de/ would like to use your current location. OK/Don't allow".

In my app I have the location of the user fetched from the CoreLocation framework. Is there a way to pass this location to this webview to avoid this alert view? Would it be somehow possible by injecting some JavaScript code or maybe somehow including geolocation in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution in the source code of [PhoneGap](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-iphone/tags/0.9.4/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Location.m) how to inject JavaScript code to a standrad webview with the location fetched from CoreLocation:

```
int epoch = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970];
float course = -1.0f;
float speed  = -1.0f;
NSString* coords =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coords: { latitude: %f, longitude: %f, altitude: %f, heading: %f, speed: %f, accuracy: %f, altitudeAccuracy: %f }",
                        newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                        newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                        newLocation.altitude,
                        course,
                        speed,
                        newLocation.horizontalAccuracy,
                        newLocation.verticalAccuracy
                     ];

NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"navigator.geolocation.setLocation({ timestamp: %d, %@ });", epoch, coords];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Hopefully somebody else can profit from this code as well.

Comment: Is this better than using geolocation from the webpage? I'm trying that but I get a double location permission dialog.

Answer (score -1):

You can call JavaScript on the page with UIWebView's

```
 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Comment: I know, but what should be specifically this JavaScript code that is expected by the website?

Comment: you'd have to talk to the website developer.  my guess is no.  they'd have to have some if/else logic in the website to say 'hey, if this is in a native app, did it send me location info? if not, guess I should ask for location permissions and get it my self".  very doubtful the web developer did that.