# Force uiwebview to use the app location permissions

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, geolocation

I have a simple app that asks the user for his current location and the user approves the request. I can also get his location and everything is working fine.

In addition I have a uiwebview that present a different url, this url also asks permission to use the user current location (although my app already has the permissions).

Can I transfer the permissions my app has to the webview?
Can I disable the popup from the webview and supply him the location?

[image]

Comment: this may help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041134/passing-geolocation-fetched-from-the-app-to-the-uiwebview

Comment: Did that link help anyone? I'm still having trouble with this exact problem

Comment: Something new with this problem? Nowadays it is still problem.

Comment: This one works, but not for ios 14 beta right now https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542677/1423345